# Fast Numeric Integration of Subgaussian Probability Densities

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Suppose I have access to a subgaussian density function $\rho: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. As a quick reminder, a density is subgaussian, if there exist constants $C,c>0$ such that  for any $t>0$
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_t(0)} \rho(t) dt < C\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{c^2}\right).
$$

Currently I'm using the change of variables
$$
t_i \mapsto \beta_i\frac{t_i}{1 - t_i^2}
$$

and integrate over $[-1, 1]^n$ using Gauss-Legendre quadrature on a grid. Unfortunately, the result is a bit sensitive to the parameter $\beta$. Is there a way to estimate $\beta$ more precisely, especially in higher dimensions? Or maybe use a different change of variables?